# Windows 7 : Facing issue in installing npm dependecies using "npm install" command

Tags: json, node.js, windows-7, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install npm dependencies mentioned in `package.json` file using `npm install` command. One thing I would like to mention that I am in company's network but I tried using admin rights also. Still getting same error. Below is the error screenshot:
[image]

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gulp-autoreload",
  "description": "The simplest Live Reload environment",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^2.14.4",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.5",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "opn": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  }
}
```

Please let me know what could be the problem.

Comment: maybe firewall is blocking connections? I had the same issue due to blocks.

Comment: Maybe your company use proxy, so you have to do some config.
[Check this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)

Comment: @kaytrance, how you resolved the issue?

Comment: I had to deal with it and wait untll I had a chance to use another network, unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

**For those who are behind a corporate web proxy:**

Setting up Node.js and using npm can be a real pain. I thought that the web proxy settings would be like the rest of the unix world and require to set the **HTTP_PROXY** and **HTTPS_PROXY** environment variables. Although I just cloned the Node repository from Github so they are already setup. What gives?

A little searching and I discover that npm uses a configuration file and it can be added to via the command line **npm config** set .... The key to getting it right is the spelling of the settings. This has bit me so many times now! Getting npm to work behind a proxy requires setting the proxy and https-proxy settings. The key is noticing the - (dash) is not an _ (underscore).

> So the full procedure is install Node.js via the installer or source.
>   Open an command prompt or terminal session and run the following
>   commands to configure npm to work with your web proxy. The commands
>   use proxy.company.com as the address and 8080 as the port

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

***You can check setting with :***

```
npm config ls -l | grep prox
```

Comment: I am using my phone network so proxy setting is not required. Thanks!

Comment: its may be the firewall of your pc, did you check its all turned off, regards. @VicJordan